# making a code that can fill in automatically a list with restrictions

Tags: python

such as the content must be only of ones and zeros with a length of 7 variables and has to be different each time. I am a rookie at python ,at coding in general i know there is a way to do it but my knowledge is limited i really hadn't tried by my own but it because I dont have any clue at all

```
def variable_creator:
    auto_variable_list = [None]*7
    content = ['0','1']
    for auto_variable_list in content:
        "auto_variable_list return 7 length with content variables"
```

The output that I expect is

```
list1=[0000000]
list2=[1000000]
list3=[0100000]
...
list128=[1111111]
```

not necessarily in that particular order but don't violate this statement for every list needs to be different content for all the 127 list

Comment: You want to create a random list of zeros and ones?

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: `from random import randint; [randint(0, 1) for _ in range(7)]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ well its not random I want to make 128 list with all 128 of 7 bits possibilities. the code form Daniel Sanchez its use full but there is the possibility that repeats its self

Comment: @juanmémdez The reason your post has been downvoted is the lack of detail. Please clarify exactly what kind of output you expect to get. Please look at [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all combinations of `[0, 1]` for a length of `7` then you can take the cartesian product of `[0, 1]` repeated `7` times, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
list(it.product([0, 1], repeat=7))

Out[]:
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 ...
```

You don't need to create independent variables for each item as you can just index them in the list:

```
In []:
vars = list(it.product([0, 1], repeat=7))
vars[0]

Out[]:
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

If you do really need them named, then a `dict` would be the appropriate structure:

```
In []:
vars = {'List{}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(it.product([0, 1], repeat=7), 1)}
vars['List128']

Out[]:
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Because you are just wanting a binary form of the number the alternative is just to convert the number to a binary string, e.g.:

```
In []:
[tuple(map(int, format(i, '07b'))) for i in range(128)]

Out[]:
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.choice` and a list comprehension:

```
import random
choices = [0,1]
[random.choice(choices) for _ in xrange(7)]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[random.choice(choices) for _ in xrange(7)]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[random.choice(choices) for _ in xrange(7)]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that really help me.